# the way antilinear operators act on scalars "passing through them"

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

i started learning quantum mechanics half a year agow and i ran into antilinear operators for the first time

at first i thought that (let $A$ be an antilinear operator on hilbert space and $\xi,\eta\in\mathbb{C}$)
$A\left(\xi|\rho\rangle+\eta|\chi\rangle\right)=\xi^*A|\rho\rangle+\eta^*A|\chi\rangle$ and so ($c \in \mathbb{C}$) $Ac=c^*A$ but everything else works the same

but then i did this:

$c_1=\langle\psi|A|\phi\rangle$ is a scalar so $c_1c_2=c_2c_1$ but $c_1c_2=\langle\psi|A|\phi\rangle c_2=\langle\psi|Ac_2|\phi\rangle=\langle\psi|c_2^*A|\phi\rangle=c_2^*c_1$ and that is problamatic
so obiosly i missed something big

id love some clarification on where i went wrong

Comment: *threw* $\rightarrow$ *through*

Comment: Agree with @peek-a-boo ... $Ac=c^*A$ is certainly wrong.  You will have to figure out what it means to multiply an antilinear operator by a scalar.

Comment: What do you mean by $Ac = c^*A$? Anyway here's the correct chain of equalities: $c_1c_2=\langle\psi|A|\phi\rangle c_2=\langle\psi|c_2A|\phi\rangle=c_2 \langle \psi|A|\phi\rangle = c_2c_1$, because $A|\phi\rangle$ is itself a "ket", so when multiplying it by a scalar $c_2$, it becomes $c_2 A|\phi\rangle$ (but you should also try to understand this without the Bra-Ket notation... which I think just completely confuses the situation)